# Retain UIViewController in TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have created my own custom TabBarController which is subclass of UITabBarController and i override this function :

```
- (void)setSelectedViewController:(UIViewController *)selectedViewController {
   [super setSelectedViewController:selectedViewController];
}
```

Inside the Tab in TabBarController, let say Tab NO.4, i can push another ViewController. So now in Tab NO.4 have a new ViewController up on it. And now, i can tab on another Tab, let say Tab NO.3. So the problem appear here, when i tab again Tab NO.4, the new ViewController is disappeared, it doesn't retain.

How can i make it retain? **Facebook** app is one of the example.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to take saperate navigation controller for each tab.

Suppose you have three tabs you nee to take three navigation controllers.

http://www.appcoda.com/storyboard-tutorial-create-tab-bar-controller-and-web-view/

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't work, so i try to debug it. Finally, i found out that the NavigationController that push the new ViewController is UIMoreNavigationController. Maybe this is the reason that the solution doesn't work. I have about 12 item in the Custom Tab Bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can take UINavigationController as a view controller instead of UIViewController in which tab you want to push a new view controller. It will automatically retain that controller after the selection changed. You also can hide navigation bar if not required.

Here is an example:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't work, so i try to debug it. Finally, i found out that the NavigationController that push the new ViewController is UIMoreNavigationController. Maybe this is the reason that the solution doesn't work. I have about 12 item in the Custom Tab Bar.